# Variable SQL query => Fatal error, fetch on boolean

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code (don't be scared about giving a value to $_POST elements, it's only for tests) :

```
$array_sql = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM voyages WHERE 1";

$_POST['numeroCommande'] = 531351351;

if (!empty($_POST['numeroCommande']))
{
    $sql .= " AND numeroCommande = :numeroCommande";
    $array_sql['numeroCommande'] = $_POST['numeroCommande'];
}

$_POST['numeroOT'] = 'JC05';

if (!empty($_POST['numeroOT']))
{
    $sql .= " AND numeroOT = :numeroOT";
    $array_sql['numeroOT'] = $_POST['numeroOT'];
}

$req = $bdd->query($sql . ' ORDER BY dateMinChargement DESC');

$data = $req->fetch();
```

I get : `"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean"`

I tried to display my array and the variable `$sql` in order to check if there was no anomaly. So I replaced `$data->$req->fetch()` by :

```
print_r($array_sql); ?> <br /> <?php
echo ($sql);
```

Here is what I get in the browser :

`Array ( [numeroCommande] => 531351351 [numeroOT] => JC05 )`

```
SELECT * FROM voyages WHERE 1 AND numeroCommande = :numeroCommande AND numeroOT = :numeroOT
```

I can't see where is the problem...

Comment: You have to use prepare() and execute() instead of query().

Comment: You put the values in `$array_sql`, but then you don't do anything with it! Shouldn't you prepare the query!

Comment: It is only when i wrote and read again this post that I saw this stupid mistake... Indeed, I have several conditions and I simplified it to post on the forum, then I could easily see. Sorry for wasted time...

Comment: You should always check the results of an operation that can fail before assuming they've returned what they should when they succeed.  PDO query returns boolean false if it couldn't execute the query (unless you've configured PDO to throw exceptions on failure).  You need to check for that.  As for why it failed it's probably due to a syntax error in your generated SQL string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not assign the value

```
 $req= $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute(array(':numeroCommande'=> $$_POST['numeroCommande'],
                               ':numeroOT'=>$$_POST['numeroOT']));
        $data =  $req->fetch();
```